# How do you process questions that are particularly salient with good answers that are closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, specific-question

I'm curious as to how folks handle questions with good answers that get closed.

Recently, I was looking for where to find the downloadable [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) for a specific instance of Java, the other day (many other days), and I looked on Stack Overflow for it. The questions was closed as being off-topic, but the answer was a lifesaver and perfectly answered:

[Where can I find the JDK documentation, and how can I read it offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986993/how-to-download-javadoc-to-read-offline)

It was a super clear question with a super clear answer. I have seen others, with thousands of upvotes, but someone has closed the question. It seems to hamper an open dialog (of Q&A) and has the unintended side effect of potentially suppressing good information.

As a long-time user, I have noticed a trend toward shutting down more of these kinds of questions (or downvoting them) that to my eyes has accelerated in recent years.

I have considered upvoting questions like this on principle, but I can't really justify doing so without discernment. Still I have taken to upvoting any that are relevant and on point... regardless of who thinks they're duplicative of some vaguely similar question or out of scope.

So, how do you handle great closed questions? Do you just let them go to the dustbin of history, do you upvote in protest, do you add comments bemoaning the offense, chat it on on the never referenced meta, or what?

Comment: Why do you believe something *should* be done about closed questions?

Comment: Also, this is a Q&A platform, not a discussion platform. Why would "open dialog" matter?

Comment: Also, I'd *really* appreciate it if you didn't try to paint curators in a negative light. That's against the CoC and it *really* undermines any point you try to make by immediately denigrating others.

Comment: @VLAZ - wrt discussion - an answer that's answered once is not answered forever. Hence the need for discussion. Different answers constitute dialog, closing questions does not. I guess I'm of the camp who thinks that the questions and answers should speak for themselves and that there is zero need for closing questions (other than for abusive situations).

Comment: "This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community" you *immediately* attacked me over challenging your premise. Well, it's clear you do not want discussion. It also paints your "open dialog" point in a very strange light. You only appreciate open dialog in words, not actions. I've VTC'd and I do advise everybody else to do so as well. Have a good day.

Comment: I've had to delete several comments left here because of incredible rudeness. If this continues, the next step will be to lock the comments and/or suspend the users who are leaving them. Downvotes aren't "stifling" a question; they're indicators of the community's opinion about the premise. Downvoting also isn't beating anyone down, because it's not a beating.

Comment: 'do you deny they exist?' Provide evidence that they do, in actionable numbers.  10 would  be good.  Meanwhile, I will continue to downvote and close the huge tide of crap thst appears at weekends...

Comment: @gnat, it's close. I do appreciate that y'all keep them around even though they are closed.

Comment: The closure of that question was incorrect. I've corrected that problem, and actually gone ahead to merge it with a duplicate question, as well as improving the quality of both questions. Thanks for bringing it to our attention. Unfortunately, your tone (and the way you engaged in comments) was a bit problematic; please try to do better there next time. Insulting the people you are trying to persuade is... not likely to be a winning strategy.

Comment: @MartinJames downvote away, if you think that's the way to do it. I participate in a good many online communities and most have some mechanism in place to keep order - stack takes a communal overlord approach that is heavy handed in my view, but if it floats your boat, motor on. The fact that you haven't apparently run into 10 good closed questions, is fascinating, but odd.

Comment: @CodyGray, thanks. I definitely didn't approach it correctly in the initial question, as I have come to realize in the intervening moments :). I'll try to take it down a notch so folks don't need counseling after having a debate.

Comment: I have not downvoted this meta.....yet.

Comment: It's not really about needing counseling. There's very little you can say to me that is going to offend me, but when you tell people that they're idiots or snowflakes, they tend to put their fingers in their ears and focus on proving you wrong, rather than considering whether there might be a kernel of truth in what you are trying to say.

Comment: [*lately that trend has accelerated.*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1701553#graph) I give you the strong uptick in closed questions last month but calling both closing and downvoting a "trend" needs a lot of statistical mangling to make it fit.

Comment: Alright, I edited for tone. Hopefully, it's less in your face.

Comment: The larger context that you need to understand is that, many years ago now, we realized that questions asking for recommendations of libraries, software tools, etc. tended to attract low-quality answers and spam. This wasn't consistent with [our goal of building a high-quality library of questions and answers about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), so we revised our rules to prohibit (or at least *severely restrict*) these types of questions. There are some subtleties to that rule, which some users are not aware of, and even were only figured out later. The site's rules evolve.

Comment: @CodyGray - Thanks for the context, it definitely makes things clearer. Before you lock the thread for rudeness or what have you and with all due deference, respect, and sincerity, how do you recommend one raise questions asking for example why a particular question is closed? I wasn't aware that there was a mechanism and probably would have just done that.

Comment: Having just spent the last half hour reading up on Meta, I realize I was hasty in my negative characterization of stack's moderation. My apologies for expressing my frustration and generalizing across stack folks. Y'all are doing good work. I use stack every day and would vote it top 10 for resources, I just don't yet understand the way y'all close questions.

Answer (score 9):

Old questions are not a good indication of what constitutes a good on-topic question, as the rules of the site have changed over time.

In this particular case, the question asks for an off-site reference material.  Such questions are currently explicitly off topic, and the question was closed for exactly that reason.

Comment: Old questions may or may not constitute a good on-topic question. Changing rules that preclude good answers aren't great. The referenced example is particularly demonstrative of this - it remains relevant through I don't know 12 revisions or more of the docs. It's important to java developers and this is reflected in its popularity.

Comment: @decuser so, what about the other literal hundreds of recommendations questions that turned into a cesspool of spam, random links, and (usually) a graveyard of dead links. Does that one Java question mean we should also reinstate those questions?

Comment: @vlaz, yup I see your point. Still, I don't like it that I run into so many closed questions that do have good answers. I'll have to think about it some more.

Answer (score 8):

Not all of the answers to that question are so great. You're under 10k, so the system doesn't tell you that there are actually 7 deleted answers, many of them deleted for moderation reasons. So, in addition to being off-topic, the question was actually drawing lots of low-quality answers.

Comment: Ah, thanks for honestly evaluating the question. That makes sense. Then perhaps there's a way to indicate that in the closure? or have a different message - I've seen "This thread has been locked due to ..." type messages elsewhere.